# Hint needed: Encryption of shared content. How to organise?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, mean-stack

I'm not quite sure how should I handle this generally.

Here's the situation:
I'm planning on a service where one can share content with other people.

- For the time being I'll name the Person who is sharing the content **Alice** and the two persons that the content is shared with **Bob** and **Carol**. Alice is a **sharer**; and Bob and Carol are **observers**
- Alice is sharing some documents …:

  - Document ***A*** is shared with nobody
  - Document ***B*** is shared with Bob
  - Document ***C*** is shared with Carol
  - Document ***D*** is shared with Bob and Carol
  - Document ***E*** is shared with Bob and is planned to be shared with Carol in the future
  - Document ***F*** is shared with nobody and is planned to be shared with Bob in the future
  - Document ***G*** is shared with Bob, but should be shared with Carol instead of Bob in the future
  - ...

Of course Bob and Carol can also be sharers, and Alice can also be an observer.

Let's assume that Bob and Carol might not be IT experts, so they wouldn't know, what to do with a public/private key pair. Alice as a sharer is the active subscriber to the system and Bob and Carol are invited to the system, so they won't know too much. Therefor the encryption/decryption should be managed in the background automatically. This would mean that the private key will be stored somewhere on the server, or wouldn't it?

You see, there are quite a lot of use cases in these scenarios, and I'm not sure on a good way to organize this.

- **Where should I store the public/private keys so that only Alice, Bob or Carol can use them and only, if they are allowed to?**
- **Should I create a public/private key pair for every user, every sharer/observer pair, or for every document?**
- **Should I decrypt the documents in the Browser (Angular) or already on the server side (express/NodeJS)?**
- **Should the keys (at least the private one) be encrypted by themselves?**
- **The documents should be stored on Amazon S3. Should I create a bucket for every user?**
- **How can I make sure that I can deny any access that I had granted before**

The tech stack does not seam to matter the most, but it's MEAN (MongoDB, Express, Angular2, NodeJS). It also uses NgRx store.

What I don't need is a full-fledged program, but only some nudges in the right direction. If you happen to have one at hand, I won't reject it :)

### Edit: Summary

Here is a short summary of the scenario:

Alice should be able to share documents with Bob. The documents should be encrypted so that only Alice and Bob can read them. The sharing is through a web app in the browser.

### Edit 2:

Oh, and BTW, Alice and Bob or Alice and Carol don't need to be online at the same moment, or at the moment that Alice shares the documents. In fact they are shared to be used several years later.

Comment: It's hard to determine exactly what you want to achieve through this system.  *Usually* when one goes to the extent of considering and/or implementing a public-key cryptography system, it is because they want to utilize end-to-end encryption e.g. the server couldn't decrypt any of the shared documents even if it wanted to.  However, you state in your question that the *private key will be stored somewhere on the server*.  This implies you don't care if the server can decrypt files or not.  If this is the case - then this is not an encryption/cryptography issue - it is an authentication one.

Comment: I'm open to any comments, thank you. But I'm afraid that I can't use and end-to-end encryption. The sharers and observers should have access from any browser on any device. Also it's not an mobile app, but a web app.

Comment: Okay - so why then do you think public key cryptography is required here?  Just encrypt all documents server-side symmetrically and manage access to the documents at an application level e.g. with permissions?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark So that means you do not think that I can add extra security by making this process extra complicated? I should only encrypt every document with the same key and permission to get these documents is enough?

Comment: If you're not implementing an end to end system, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- Encrypt data at rest
- Ensure your application only grants file access to authorized users

Systems such as Amazon S3 normally create a **per-object encryption key** to encrypt the files. Then, that key is encrypted with a master key. The master key is kept in the Key Management System and can never be exported.

This way, if one of the encryption keys is obtained, it can only be used to decrypt one file. Or, if a government demands access to a file and therefore demand the encryption key, they can only read that one file.

Amazon S3 can manage all of the above for you automatically by using server-side encryption and AWS Key Management Service.

Comment: What does *at rest* mean? I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Will I as AWS admin be able to read the files? Because I shouldn't be

Comment: The AWS Key Management Service is not part of S3, is it?

Comment: "Encryption at rest" means when data is stored on disk (as opposed to Encryption in Transit, which means when the data is moving between systems). Amazon S3 can automatically use the AWS KMS, or it can use its own server-side encryption. It automatically handles the encryption and decryption. Therefore, if somebody is authorized to access a file, it automatically decrypts it and provides it in an unencrypted state. You will never see the encrypted version of the file. See: [Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html)

Answer (score 0):

> you do not think that I can add extra security by making this process extra complicated?

Making the process more complicated is usually prone to more complicated mistakes.

In theory - you may create an end-to-end security by encrypting content by a content key and then encrypt the content key for each accessing user's public key. Though each user needs to have its own private key by himself and able to use it.

> already on the server side (express/NodeJS)

Ok, you have a server side application so that makes the things easier.

Seeing your requirements you may not need to manage the access directly on S3.  To simplify the things - you may create an application which decides which user may or may not access the content. Then the application may provide the content either directly (e.g. proxying the S3 content) or providing a signed url for access the content. That assumes you keep the application credentials secure.

> The documents should be encrypted so that only Alice and Bob can read them. 
>   ... 
>    Therefor the encryption/decryption should be managed in the background automatically.

You may encrypt the content on S3 itself, though it will be transparent to the users, they will receive the content plain.

> If you happen to have one at hand, I won't reject it :)

You may have check any content management or portal solutions, they provide access and content sharing by defaut (Aflresco, Liferay, ...) or any feasible CMS system